# Building a large Map of functions? (F#)

Tags: f#

I am trying to build a F# console application which calls a library to solve a collection of maths/programming problems.

My approach involves building a large map of solver functions (specifically a `Map<int, (unit -> int)>` ).

The app then simply asks for an integer id and calls the appropriate solver to display the solution (the solution has to run code + run a timer so can't just store a string).

My initial setup is as shown below. However I'm aware this will quickly get messy as I add more solutions - after 100 solutions I would have >> 1,000 lines (and seems silly to be adding them to the Map one line at a time).

One approach I am considering is to create a .fs file for each Problem, and calling the module e.g. `Problem001`.
Then I would have ~100 lines in the Map building function (e.g. `Map.Add(1, Problem001.solver)`).

My question is: Is the above idea the best approach (and if so, is there a cleaner way of bringing all the different modules together into one Map?)

And if not, what is the best approach?

Class Library: Library.fs

```
namespace Library

module Problems = 
    let Titles = 
         Map.empty
             .Add(1, "Title1") // etc
    let Descriptions = 
         Map.empty
             .Add(1, "Desc1") // etc

module Solutions = 
    let solution1 () =
        // logic & solution annotation, unique to each problem
        printfn "Solution annotation/text"
        ans // return integer answer

    let solution2 () = // etc
        printfn "blah"
        ans

    let solvers = 
        Map.empty
            .Add(1, solution1)
            .Add(2, solution2)
```

Console Application: Program.fs

```
let main argv = 
    // request & validate input
    printfn Problems.Descriptions.[problemId]
    let solver = Solutions.solvers.[problemId]
    solver()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest creating a type to contain the problem Title, Description, and Solution.  Then, I would create one or more modules containing functions that return the solutions to each problem, using a standard naming convention, such as `problemN` where `N` is the `problemId`.  With that defined, I would just use reflection to find the function that returns the solution for the given problem, and invoke it:

```
open System.Reflection

type Problem =
    { 
        Title: string
        Description: string
        Solution: int  // This could even be a function, int -> int or whatever
    }

module Solutions =
    let problem1 () =
        { Title = "#1"
          Description = "The first problem"
          Solution = 42
        }

let printSolution problemId =
    match Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes() |> Array.tryFind (fun t -> t.Name = "Solutions") with
    | Some solutions ->
        match solutions.GetMethod(sprintf "problem%d" problemId) with
        | null -> 
            printfn "Solution to Problem %d not found" problemId
        | func -> 
            let problem = func.Invoke(null, [||]) |> unbox<Problem>
            printfn "Problem %d:  %s" problemId problem.Title
            printfn "    %s" problem.Description
            printfn "    Solution = %d" problem.Solution
    | None -> printfn "Solutions module not found"
```

You could return the `Problem` instance instead of printing it, in your real library, but as defined you would call it as such:

```
printSolution 1
```

And it would print the following:

```
Problem 1:  #1
    The first problem        
    Solution = 42
```

**EDIT**

Combining an answer to ifo20's question in the comments with the great suggestion from cadull to use custom attributes, here's a more flexible solution that will allow defining the solutions in many different modules/files, and doesn't rely on the naming convention to find them.

```
open System
open System.Reflection

type Problem =
    { 
        Title: string
        Description: string
        Solution: int  // This could even be a function, int -> int or whatever
    }

[<AllowNullLiteral>]
type SolutionModuleAttribute () =
    inherit Attribute()

[<AllowNullLiteral>]
type SolutionAttribute (problemId: int) =
    inherit Attribute()
    member __.ProblemId = problemId

[<SolutionModule>]
module SomeSolutions =
    [<Solution(1)>]
    let firstProblem () =
        { Title = "#1"
          Description = "The first problem"
          Solution = 42
        }

[<SolutionModule>]
module MoreSolutions =
    [<Solution(2)>]
    let secondProblem () =
        { Title = "#2"
          Description = "The second problem"
          Solution = 17
        }


let findSolutions () =
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes() 
    |> Array.filter (fun t -> t.GetCustomAttribute<SolutionModuleAttribute>() |> isNull |> not)
    |> Array.collect (fun t -> t.GetMethods())
    |> Array.choose (fun m -> 
        match m.GetCustomAttribute<SolutionAttribute>() with
        | null -> None
        | attribute -> Some (attribute.ProblemId, fun () -> m.Invoke(null, [||]) |> unbox<Problem>))
    |> Map.ofArray


let printSolution =
    let solutions = findSolutions()
    fun problemId ->
        match solutions |> Map.tryFind problemId with
        | Some func ->
            let problem = func()
            printfn "Problem %d:  %s" problemId problem.Title
            printfn "    %s" problem.Description
            printfn "    Solution = %d" problem.Solution
        | None -> 
            printfn "Solution for Problem %d not found" problemId
```

The biggest change, other than using the attributes to identify the solutions and the modules that contain them, is the refactoring of the lookup logic into its own function.  This now returns a `Map<int, (unit -> Problem)>` so you only have to traverse the assembly and find the solutions by their attributes once, then you can use the map to lookup the solutions to each problem.

The usage and the output of the `printSolution` function remain the same:

```
printSolution 2

Problem 2:  #2
    The second problem
    Solution = 17
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I haven't used reflection much but If I understand you correctly: doesn't this approach still require that I have one module ('Solutions') that contains all my functions problem1, problem2 etc? And as I can't define a module in more than one file, this will still result in one big .fs file? Would it make more sense to match dynamically within the GetTypes() call rather than the GetMethod() call?

Comment: A custom attribute might be useful - [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44804767/f-create-custom-attribute-to-expression).

Comment: @ifo20, I've edited my answer to include a more general solution that addresses your concerns by incorporating cadull's suggestion.