# Is there any DataRowAttribute in f# unit testing?

Tags: c#, f#

In c# I can do this ([DataRowAttribute (c#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.datarowattribute?view=mstest-net-1.2.0))

```
[TestMethod]
[DataRow(1,2,3)]
[DataRow(2,2,4)]
public void TestSum (int x, int y, int expected)
```

I could not find a way to do this in f#. If it does not exist, how can I create such attribute for f# unit testing ?

---

UPDATE

Providing code after Jonathon Chase's suggestion with `[<DataRow (2,4,6)>]`.
Unfortunately the test `AddTest` is not discovered by the test runner.

```
namespace FsharpTests

open System
open Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

[<TestClass>]
type TestClass () =

    [<TestMethod>]
    member this.TestMethodPassing() =
        Assert.IsTrue(true);

    [<TestMethod>]
    [<DataRow (1,2,3)>]
    [<DataRow (2,4,6)>]
     member this.AddTest(a, b, expected) = 
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, a+b); //won't be discovered by the test runner
```

Comment: Have you [seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44804767/f-create-custom-attribute-to-expression) that, it may be of help.

Comment: Equivalent syntax for attributes in F# would be `[<TestMethod>]` `[<DataRow(1,2,3)>]`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @JonathonChase Yes. But the test runner is not updating or seeing it, the test method is not even mentionned among tests.

Comment: Are they members of a type with the `[<TestClass>]` attribute? Have you looked at [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-fsharp-with-mstest#creating-the-first-test)? It would help if you provided some of your F# code.

Comment: @JonathonChase Check out the code added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to lie with *typing* the arguments.

When I adjust your test to the following it *does* work (not the typed arguments):

```
namespace UnitTestProject1

open Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

[<TestClass>]
type TestClass () =

    [<TestMethod>]
    [<DataRow (1,2,3)>]
    [<DataRow (2,4,6)>]
    member this.AddTest (a:int, b:int, expected:int) = 
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, a+b);
```

Now I get the two testcases passing in the results:
[image]